# First Angular JS App - issue loading service

Tags: angularjs-service

I do hate asking new questions and in fact this is my first I believe, but you can take my word for it that I have tried my utmost to find an answer without leaning on you guys.

It's very straight forward, building up my first silly Angular JS App but seem to have some syntactic error on my hands as so far as I can tell everything seems right. Simply trying to get used to services with a simple factory returning some data, but I can't even do that :,(

The problem is with the menuService, its in the service.js file, it simply returns an array through a factory, but I'm told it's undefined.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'getData' of undefined
    at new  (app.js:49)

Line 49 is where I assign       $scope.menuItems = menuService.getData;

Thanks!

My index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Jan Michael Vincent</title>
    <meta name="description" content="A sample Angular app featuring Jan Michael Vincent">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <link href="bower_components/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <script src="service.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="JMV">


    <!-- HEADER -->
    <div class="header" ng-controller="mainController">
        <img class="header_logo" ng-src="{{title.logo}}">
        <h1>{{title.value}} {{title.total+1}}</h1>
    </div>


    <!-- ALERTS -->
    <div class="alerts">
        <div ng-controller="alertController">
            <uib-alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</uib-alert>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- ----- CONTENT & SIDEBAR ----- -->
      <div class="section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">


              <!-- SIDEBAR -->
              <div class="col-md-3" ng-controller="menuController">   
                <h3 ng-repeat="item in menuItems"> <a href src="{{item.link}}"> {{item.name}} </a> </h3>
              </div>


              <!-- CONTENT -->
              <div class="col-md-9" ng-controller="contentController">

                <div class="row">
                  <h2> Our Team of Developers </h2>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="member in teamMembers">
                      <img src="{{member.img}}" class="center-block img-circle img-responsive">
                      <h3 class="text-center">{{member.name}}</h3>
                      <p class="text-center">{{member.title}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <p ng-if="myBool">{{content.value}}</p>
                <button ng-click="myBool=!myBool">Tog-L</button>


              </div>


            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

    <!-- FOOTER -->


</body></html>
```

My app.js:

```
    'use strict';

angular.module('JMV', [
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'serv'
    ])
    .controller('mainController', function($scope){
        $scope.title={};
        $scope.title.value="Jan Michael Vincent";
        $scope.title.logo="img/logo.png";
        $scope.title.total=2999;
    })
    .controller('contentController', function($scope){
        $scope.myBool = true;
        $scope.content={};
        $scope.content.value="First Content Butch";
        $scope.content.date="21/04/16";

        function toggleOn () {
            if (myBool) {
                myBool = false;
            } else {
                myBool = true;
            }
        };

        $scope.teamMembers = [
            {
                'name' : "Tiny Rick",
                'img' : "img/rick.jpg",
                'title' : "Science guy"
            },
            {
                'name' : "Morty",
                'img' : "img/morty.jpg",
                'title' : "Loon"
            },
            {
                'name' : "Jerry",
                'img' : "img/jerry.jpg",
                'title' : "Employee"
            }
        ];
    })
    .controller('menuController', [
        'menuService',
        function($scope, menuService){
        $scope.menuItems = menuService.getData;
    }])
    .controller('alertController', function ($scope) {
      $scope.alerts = [
        //{ type: 'danger', msg: 'Accept our Cookie Policy or GTFO!' },
        { type: 'danger', msg: 'You are not logged in!' }
      ];

      $scope.closeAlert = function(index) {
        $scope.alerts.splice(index, 1);
      };
    });
```

My service.js:

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    angular.module('serv', [])
        .factory('menuService', menuService);

        function menuService () {

            var service = {
                getData: getData,
                putData: putData
            }

            return service;

            //////

            function getData() {
                return [{
                    'name' : 'Home',
                    'link' : 'index.html'
                },
                {
                    'name' : 'About',
                    'link' : 'about.html'
                },
                {
                    'name' : 'Contact',
                    'link' : 'contact.html'
                }];
            }

            function putData() {
                //TODO
            }

        };
})();
```

Any help would be massively appreciated, once I can understand what I'm doing wrong here I should be away with it. Many thanks in advance :D

N

Comment: Can you point out where you have the errors and what they are? Please do that by editing your original question.

Comment: Sincere apologies, I thought I had included this, it is added now [also below]. Many thanks.

The problem is with the menuService, its in the service.js file, it simply returns an array through a factory, but I'm told it's undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is related to Dependency Injection.

When injecting components into the controller using the Inline Array Annotation, you first supply a list of string dependency names, followed by the function declaration, which accepts the exact same number of parameters as the array, in the exact same order.

In your code, you have:

```
.controller('menuController', [
    'menuService',
    function($scope, menuService){
```

This declaration has one string value, but two function parameters.  These are not in sync.  In practice, this will set `$scope` equal to your `'menuService'` object, and `menuService` will be undefined, and neither will perform the way you would expect.

To correct this, ensure that your parameter list and actual parameters are in sync:

```
.controller('menuController', [
    '$scope', 'menuService',
    function($scope, menuService){
```

Comment: Ok that's brilliant thank you so much. The errors are gone and I understand exactly why I messed it up. So should $scope always be explicity defined as a dependency? I seem to be able to get away without it in other controllers, is that only because there are no other dependencies? I assume it's bad practice not to include it so? Thanks again :D Super quick response

Comment: `$scope` is a service, just like any other angular component.  What `$scope` really is internally is an object that holds the bindings for the two way DOM communication.  You don't *strictly* have to inject `$scope`, but in practice, you will probably need it in most controllers, if you want to change variables in the DOM.  There are other more advanced ways to deal with the DOM, but they are a bit too lengthy to discuss in this format.

Comment: A true gentleman, thank you for your time it's really appreciated :)

Answer (score -1):

Here you go. I am too lazy to find the mistake in your code. Rather than doing that I'll post some code from a project of mine that I know works. See if you can reverse engineer that to work with your code. I recommend stripping anything useless away from the code one step at a time. Until it runs.

```
'use strict';

//define module and dependencies to other modules
angular.module('MyModule', ['pascalprecht.translate', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);

//define translations
angular.module('MyModule').config(function ($translateProvider) {

    $translateProvider.translations('en', {
        HEADLINE: 'Hello there, This is my awesome app!',
        INTRO_TEXT: 'And it has i18n support!'
    });

    $translateProvider.translations('de', {
        HEADLINE: 'Hey, das ist meine großartige App!',
        INTRO_TEXT: 'Und sie untersützt mehrere Sprachen!'
    });

    $translateProvider.translations('sv', {
        HEADLINE: 'Hejsan detta är min awesome app!',
        INTRO_TEXT: 'Und sie untersützt mehrere Sprachen!'
    });

    //$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('de');
    //$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('sv');
});

//define services
angular.module('MyModule').service('TabService', ['$log', function ($log) {

    //fetches the url of the current window and active tab
    this.requestCurrentTabData = function (callback) {

        if (!chrome.tabs) {
            $log.error("chrome.tabs api is only available when running as a browser extension");
            return callback("request error");
        }

        chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (result) {
            var tab = result[0];
            callback({
                url: tab.url,
                title: tab.title
                //favIconUrl: tab.favIconUrl
            });
        });

    };
}]);

//define directives
angular.module('MyModule').directive('myAutoFocus', ['$document', function ($document) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attributes, controller) {
            angular.element($document).ready(function () {
                element[0].focus();
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: It's not really a good idea to start an answer off with "I'm too lazy to fix your code, so here's my code that does something completely different".

Comment: that is much appreciated thank you I will try now to use this. Claies, you are not wrong but to be fair I had forgotten to include even an inkling of what the issue was so I didn't make it easy! I have included a description of the actual problem now in the original post. many thanks

Comment: I copied your code to a test environment, located the error, found a fix, and wrote an answer.   There is no point to writing an answer declaring that you're too lazy to actually try to help.

Comment: Wow thank you, hopefully I can pay it forward in future :D many thanks again